# this.idle.onTimeout.observers.length = 0 is giving error Msg Property 'observers' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<number>

Tags: angular, typescript

After updating RXJS V7  , `this.idle.onTimeout.observers.length = 0`
giving following error msg ==>
Property 'observers' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter'

How to fix this, what i have to use instead of observers.